# End of line comments and before after key comments made using ruamel.yaml are not dumped

Tags: python, file, yaml, ruamel.yaml

Comments made using `.yaml_set_comment_before_after_key()` and `.yaml_add_eol_comment()` on a newly created  `ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap` are not shown in the dumped string. See the expected vs actual output below.

Note that, ruamel.yaml==0.17.4 is the latest version that produces the expected output. Any versions later than this otherwise does not (see below).

```py
# Minimal reproducible example
import ruamel.yaml

data = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()
data['key'] = 'value'
data.yaml_set_start_comment('Start comment', indent=0)
data.yaml_set_comment_before_after_key('key', before='Before comment', indent=0)
data.yaml_add_eol_comment('End-of-line comment', 'key', column=0)

yaml_str = ruamel.yaml.dump(data, Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper)
print(yaml_str)
```

Using:
Python 3.10.8
ruamel.yaml==0.17.32
ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.7

By going through ruamel.yaml's version history, I have found that the latest ruamel version that produces the expected output to be 0.17.4 (Can be installed using `pip install ruamel.yaml==0.17.4`)
I don't understand why versions higher than this do not produce the expected output anymore. Is this perhaps a bug since April 2021?

Expected output:

```
# Start comment
# Before comment
key: value # End-of-line comment
```

Actual output (using ruamel.yaml==0.17.32):

```
# Start comment
key: value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your code is not minimal, in that it creates a `StringIO` buffer and then
`print`s the contents of that buffer. Don't do this:

```
yaml_str = ruamel.yaml.dump(data, Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper)
print(yaml_str)
```

just directly stream to `sys.stdout`  ( with `dump(data, sys.stdout)` ), that is more concise, is faster and uses far less memory.

What *I* don't understand is why you expect to be able to continue to use deprecated functions when you upgrade
to a newer version, and then expect them to continue to work
as usual. You should be using a `YAML()` instance:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
 
data = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()
data['key'] = 'value'
data.yaml_set_start_comment('Start comment', indent=0)
data.yaml_set_comment_before_after_key('key', before='Before comment', indent=0)
data.yaml_add_eol_comment('End-of-line comment', 'key', column=0)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
# Start comment
# Before comment
key: value # End-of-line comment
```

And pin the version of ruamel.yaml that you are using, because those internal routines for handling
comments will change in the future.

Comment: I hadn't realised that I was using a deprecated function all along, my bad. As for why I hadn't opted to file stream directly to `sys.stdout` is that I wish to use this dumped result as a value in my program that I can use, which I should have mentioned in the original post.

Comment: In the case you need to postprocess the YAML output, look at the `transform` argument to dump. If not you might need to install `ruamel.yaml.string` or `ruamel.yaml.bytes` and use one of those plugins.  Standard `dump` no longer allows not to provide a stream and does no longer support the inefficient `print(YAML().dump(data))`

Comment: @Anthon: could you please demonstrate how to use `yaml_end_comment_extend` to create/append end comment?